# open an image in second page using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a button in **`index.html`**. after click on this button, I want to *append* an image in body section of **`page2`**. The following code only opens **`page2`** but the rest of code doesn't work. What I am doing wrong? thanks

```
function ready()
{
    var w    = window.open("Page2.html");
    w.onload = function(){
        var p = document.createElement("img");
        x.setAttribute("src", "ts_WWW_2016w03.jpg");
        x.setAttribute("width", "304");
        x.setAttribute("height", "228");
        w.document.body.appendChild(p);
    };
}
```

Comment: I think as soon as your second page opens, focus shifts to it and that's why your rest of the code doesn't work. Maybe you should send your parameters in query string to second page and use javascript to open the image using those parameters.

Comment: `window.open` results reloading page entirely so `w.onload` never call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Method 1:

One way to do this is by making use of query string, it could be like this:

[**Plunker Demo 1**](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/SRRwkJjR7pylnCTPKzyf/)

**page1.html**

```
<h1>Page 1</h1>
<button id="clickMe">Open New Page</button>

<script>
    document.getElementById("clickMe").addEventListener('click', ready);

    function ready() {
        var $s = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city/2/',
        $w = '400px',
        $h = '200px',

        //we combine the three into one string using '&' as a delimiter
        $qs = $s + '&' + $w + '&' + $h;

        //then we add that final string as query to the href
        window.open('page2.html?' + $qs);
    }
</script>
```

**page2.html**

```
<h1>Page 2</h1>

<script>
    // we first grab page href, extract that string we injected in
    // page1 which comes after the '?' mark.
    // then we split the string into an array with three elements.
    var a = location.href,
        b = a.substring(a.indexOf("?") + 1),
        qStrings = b.split('&'),
        $img = document.createElement("img");

    // because of how we combined the string in page 1, the first
    // element of the array represents the 'src'
    // the secodn elements represents the 'width' and the last
    // on is the 'hight'.
    console.log(qStrings);
    $img.setAttribute("src", qStrings[0]);
    $img.setAttribute("width", qStrings[1]);
    $img.setAttribute("height", qStrings[2]);

    //then we append the image
    document.body.appendChild($img);
</script>
```

---

#### Method 2:

You can also achieve it using [**`sessionStorage`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [**`localStorage`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage),
 IMHO this is better because the url in the address bar of page2 tab won't look like a mess and could be a better way to avoid errors comparing to method 1.

[**Plunker Demo 2**](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/77Sd9StF5SfStNJvsNI8/)

**page1.html**

```
<h1>Page 1</h1>
<button id="clickMe">Open New Page</button>

<script>
  document.getElementById("clickMe").addEventListener('click', ready);

  // we create three session keys for src, width and height
  // and we set their values, then we launch page2
  function ready() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('$src', 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city/2/');
    sessionStorage.setItem('$width', '400px');
    sessionStorage.setItem('$height', '200px');

    window.open('page2.html');
  }
</script>
```

**page2.html**

```html
<h1>Page 3</h1> <a href="index.html">back to page 1</a>

<script>
    // First, just in case a user opens page2 before clicking the button in page1,
    // we check if the session item we need have been set or not, if yes we proceed
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('$src') && sessionStorage.getItem('$width') && sessionStorage.getItem('$height')) {
        var $img = document.createElement("img");

        // we get the session values and set them as values of
        // the image attributes, then we append the image 
        $img.setAttribute("src", sessionStorage.getItem('$src'));
        $img.setAttribute("width", sessionStorage.getItem('$width'));
        $img.setAttribute("height", sessionStorage.getItem('$height'));
        document.body.appendChild($img);

        // this is optional but it might be a good practice to
        // remove the session items
        sessionStorage.removeItem('$src');
        sessionStorage.removeItem('$width');
        sessionStorage.removeItem('$height');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have through test on last version of chrome. 
the x is not define: x.setAttribute.

```
function ready()
{
    var w = window.open("Page2.html");
    w.onload = function(){
        var p = document.createElement("img");
        p.setAttribute("src", "images/ts_WWW_2016w03.jpg");
        p.setAttribute("width", "304");
        p.setAttribute("height", "228");
        w.document.body.appendChild(p);
    };
}
ready();
```

Comment: Explain to me what your reasoning is for this answer?

Comment: Thank you. I tried your second method and it worked. I was trying to figure it out for a week.

Comment: Is there a way instead of opening a new page, replace page1 with page 2?